# How to *ngFor through JSON (interface array)? Error TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, ngfor, angular15

I know similar questions were asked several times before, but couldn't find my answer there.
I would like to iterate through an '*interface*' array as you can see in the *HTML* part.

*Angular component:*

```
export class PlayerComponent {

  constructor(private playerApiService: PlayerApiService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPlayers();
  }

  objectKeys = Object.keys;  

  players: IPlayer[] = [];
  
  getPlayers(): void {
    this.playerApiService.getPlayers().subscribe(players => {
      this.players = players;
    });
  }
}
```

*Angular HTML:*

```
<div *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(players)">
    Key: {{key}}

    <div *ngFor="let player of players[key]">
        {{player.name}}
        {{player.isAttending}}
    </div>
</div>
```

*JSON:*

```
{
  "player": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Andrew",
      "isAttending": false
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Blair",
      "isAttending": true
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Carl",
      "isAttending": true
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Diane",
      "isAttending": false
    }
  ]
}
```

*Angular interface:*

```
export interface IPlayer {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    isAttending: boolean
}
```

It works without the *interface*, but how it is done by using the *interface*?

```
//players: IPlayer[] = [];
players: { [key: string]: any } = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of your JSON is

```
interface Players{
   player: IPlayer[]
}

// or type Players = Record<string,IPlayer[]>
```

So you should have:

```
players: Players = {player:[]};
```

To sumup:

```
export class PlayerComponent {

  constructor(private playerApiService: PlayerApiService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPlayers();
  }

  objectKeys = Object.keys;  

  players: { [key: string]: IPlayer[] } = {}
  
  getPlayers(): void {
    this.playerApiService
         .getPlayers()
         .subscribe((players:{ [key: string]: IPlayer[] }) => {
            this.players = players;
         });
  }
}


// Warning, this.playerApiService.getPlayers() should return the type { [key: string]: IPlayer[] }
```

Comment: You mean an interface inside an interface?

Comment: Yes, if your JSON is right, `getPlayers()` returns `Players` which contains the `IPlayer`

Comment: Or if you want a shortcut, you can just do `players: { [key: string]: IPlayer[] } = [];`

Comment: ```players: { [key: string]: IPlayer[] } = [];```  won't work. *Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: IPlayer[]; }'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'never[]'.*

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: `players: { [key: string]: IPlayer[] } = {}`

Comment: *Type 'IPlayer[]' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: IPlayer[]; }'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'IPlayer[]'* in ```this.players = players;```

Comment: I have added to my answer, the full solution

Comment: I get the *No overload matches this call* error as in the comments under @don-delice solution.

Comment: Please create a stackblitz example,  otherwise it will be endless

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3m3qqx

Comment: `getPlayers(): Observable<IPlayer[]>`. It's wrong. It should be just `Players` as well for `this.httpClient.get<IPlayer[]>('/assets/player.json');`. It should be `this.httpClient.get<Players>('/assets/player.json');`

Comment: Something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ks6jv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fplayer.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fplayer-api.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fplayer%2Fplayer.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fplayer%2Fplayer.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Perhaps my question is misleading, but the interface must stay as it is. So, no interface inside interface - I don't know if this is good practice, but that's a question for another thread. What I would like to achieve is to iterate what I get - https://i.postimg.cc/j201QSb9/player.png . I guess I'm supposed to use objectKeys or keyvalue, but by trying to do so, I get the error mentioned in my question.

Comment: But your interface is wrong. `players` is not equal to your `IPlayer[]`. In anycase, you need to change your code

Comment: Well, that works ```this.httpClient.get<IPlayer[]>('/assets/player.json')``` and ```players: IPlayer[] = []``` is populated. So the question remains, how to iterate ***players***?

Comment: Typescript can't know the type of `'/assets/player.json'`. So it believes your call `IPlayer[]` which is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, but that's for another thread. I just wanna know how to iterate the result. It doesn't matter if it's right or wrong. The JSON is temporary, in the end I will get data from a db. Forget how ***players*** is populated and imagine that you have it that way (and you can't change how it gets served), but you need to iterate it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you have not mentioned the type on the parameter when subscribing to the observable, you can try to do like this :

```
  getPlayers(): void {
      this.playerApiService.getPlayers().subscribe((players:IPlayer) => {
      this.players = players;
    });
  }
```

This should work properly but make sure that you have imported the interface in your component.  This error occurred because typescript is strict about respecting types.

I hope this helps, let me know if any further questions

Comment: *No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(observerOrNext?: Partial<Observer<IPlayer[]>> | ((value: IPlayer[]) => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(players: IPlayer) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<Observer<IPlayer[]>> | ((value: IPlayer[]) => void) | undefined'.
      Type '(players: IPlayer) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: IPlayer[]) => void'.
        Types of parameters 'players' and 'value' are incompatible.*

Comment: * Type 'IPlayer[]' is missing the following properties from type 'IPlayer': id, name, isAttending
  Overload 2 of 2, '(next?: ((value: IPlayer[]) => void) | null | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | null | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(players: IPlayer) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: IPlayer[]) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'players' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'IPlayer[]' is not assignable to type 'IPlayer'.*